# Display trailing zeros with signif

Tags: r, gt, significant-digits

I am creating tables displaying numerical data with the gt package in R.  I need to display 2 significant figures in my table and want to show trailing zeros if relevant (for aesthetic purposes).  For example, I need the number 0.301 to display as 0.30.  The number 0.000502 to display as 0.00050.  How do I do this?  The function signif() displays these values as 0.3 and 0.0005.

Comment: https://gt.rstudio.com/reference/fmt_number.html, see the `n_sigfig` parameter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just format the values using `sprintf` before printing them:

```
sprintf('%#.2g', c(0.301, 0.000502))
[1] "0.30"    "0.00050"
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, further to this, how would I get sprintf to not put a decimal place if the number is an integer? I want it to display 11 as "11" not "11."

```sprintf('%#.2g', 11)```